# get input value and change div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the span with the input value what is the error on my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('#tnx-status').val() = 'publish'){
    $("#status-p").html("Complited")
  }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="tnxst" type="hidden" id="tnx-status" value="publish" />
<span id="status-p"></span>
```

Comment: Look at your browser's debugging console.  It's telling you exactly what the problem is.  Or even just click "Run code snippet" in your own question.

Comment: I was trying but I can't fix this

Comment: When you were trying, what was the error message?  What line of code did it refer to?  What is the error message telling you and how are you trying to apply that information to your code?

Comment: "ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side", "lineno": 16,
  "colno": 7 but as a new on jquery I can't understand this .

Comment: The problem is that you have a typo in your code.  You're using `=` instead of `==` (or `===`).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion I got this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use comparison operator `===` instead of assignment operator `=`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('#tnx-status').val() === 'publish'){
    $("#status-p").html("Complited")
  }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="tnxst" type="hidden" id="tnx-status" value="publish" />
<span id="status-p"></span>
```